# What does "seem oneself" mean?

Tags: meaning

> "If truth be told, the Hand had not **seemed quite himself** for some
>   times," Pycelle said.

I encountered this sentence from *the Game of Throne*. I have looked up the dictionaries and googled, but I cannot find the meaning of **seem oneself**. Does this whole sentence mean that what others said about the death of the Hand is not consistent with the characteristic of the Hand?

This whole  paragraph is

> "If truth be told, the Hand had not **seemed quite himself** for some
>   times," Pycelle said. "We had sat together on council many a year, he
>   and I, and the signs were there to read, but I put them down to the
>   great burdens he had borne so faithfully for so long. Those broad
>   shoulders were weighed down by all the cares of the realm, and more
>   besides. His son was ever sickly, and his lady wife so anxious that
>   she would scarcely let the boy out of here sight. It was enough to
>   weary even a strong man, and the Lord Jon was not young. Small wonder
>   if he seemed melancholy and tired. Or so I thought at the time. Yet
>   now I am less certain." He gave a ponderous shake of his head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Seem oneself*** should be understood from each word's meaning. The verb [***seem***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seem) means:

> ***Give the impression*** of being something or having a particular quality:
>   *it seemed a dismal town.*

And [***oneself***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oneself) means:

> In one’s ***normal and individual state of body or mind***; not
>   influenced by others:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

"Not seemed quite himself" thus means:

> He was not speaking, acting or behaving in a way that indicated his
>   normal (usual) state of body or mind.

In other words, he was acting strange and he looked like going through changes in his body and mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the meaning of the phrase "seem oneself" if you look up the reflexive pronoun yourself or himself in a dictionary.

If somebody looks to be in his normal physical or mental state,or he looks to be behaving as usual, you can say "He seems/looks himself".